# Error while compiling InfluxDB library for ESP32

Tags: c++, arduino, influxdb

newbie here.
I am trying to compile the BasicWrite.ino example in the InfluxDB library for a ESP32 Dev board for personal project. The code is:

```
 * Basic Write Example code for InfluxDBClient library for Arduino
 * Data can be immediately seen in a InfluxDB UI: wifi_status measurement
 * Enter WiFi and InfluxDB parameters below
 *
 * Measures signal level of the actually connected WiFi network
 * This example supports only InfluxDB running from unsecure (http://...)
 * For secure (https://...) or Influx Cloud 2 use SecureWrite example
 **/

#if defined(ESP32)
#include <WiFiMulti.h>
WiFiMulti wifiMulti;
#define DEVICE "ESP32"
#elif defined(ESP8266)
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
ESP8266WiFiMulti wifiMulti;
#define DEVICE "ESP8266"
#endif

#include <InfluxDbClient.h>

// WiFi AP SSID
#define WIFI_SSID "ssid"
// WiFi password
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "password"
// InfluxDB  server url. Don't use localhost, always server name or ip address.
// E.g. http://192.168.1.48:8086 (In InfluxDB 2 UI -> Load Data -> Client Libraries), 
#define INFLUXDB_URL "influxdb-url"
// InfluxDB 2 server or cloud API authentication token (Use: InfluxDB UI -> Load Data -> Tokens -> <select token>)
#define INFLUXDB_TOKEN "toked-id"
// InfluxDB 2 organization id (Use: InfluxDB UI -> Settings -> Profile -> <name under tile> )
#define INFLUXDB_ORG "org"
// InfluxDB 2 bucket name (Use: InfluxDB UI -> Load Data -> Buckets)
#define INFLUXDB_BUCKET "bucket"
// InfluxDB v1 database name 
//#define INFLUXDB_DB_NAME "database"

// InfluxDB client instance
InfluxDBClient client(INFLUXDB_URL, INFLUXDB_ORG, INFLUXDB_BUCKET, INFLUXDB_TOKEN);
// InfluxDB client instance for InfluxDB 1
//InfluxDBClient client(INFLUXDB_URL, INFLUXDB_DB_NAME);

// Data point
Point sensor("wifi_status");

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Connect WiFi
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  wifiMulti.addAP(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  while (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Set InfluxDB 1 authentication params
  //client.setConnectionParamsV1(INFLUXDB_URL, INFLUXDB_DB_NAME, INFLUXDB_USER, INFLUXDB_PASSWORD);

  // Add constant tags - only once
  sensor.addTag("device", DEVICE);
  sensor.addTag("SSID", WiFi.SSID());

  // Check server connection
  if (client.validateConnection()) {
    Serial.print("Connected to InfluxDB: ");
    Serial.println(client.getServerUrl());
  } else {
    Serial.print("InfluxDB connection failed: ");
    Serial.println(client.getLastErrorMessage());
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Store measured value into point
  sensor.clearFields();
  // Report RSSI of currently connected network
  sensor.addField("rssi", WiFi.RSSI());
  // Print what are we exactly writing
  Serial.print("Writing: ");
  Serial.println(client.pointToLineProtocol(sensor));
  // If no Wifi signal, try to reconnect it
  if (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Wifi connection lost");
  }
  // Write point
  if (!client.writePoint(sensor)) {
    Serial.print("InfluxDB write failed: ");
    Serial.println(client.getLastErrorMessage());
  }

  //Wait 10s
  Serial.println("Wait 10s");
  delay(10000);
}
```

Here is what I got:

```
C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.cpp: In member function 'bool InfluxDBClient::init()':

C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.cpp:150:28: error: 'class WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'setInsecure'

             wifiClientSec->setInsecure();

                            ^

C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.cpp: In function 'String escapeJSONString(String&)':

C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.cpp:714:18: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope

     for (char c: value)

                  ^

C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.cpp:714:18: note: suggested alternative:

In file included from c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\string:51:0,

                 from c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\random:40,

                 from c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\bits\stl_algo.h:66,

                 from c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\algorithm:62,

                 from C:\Users\zjwa1\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.2\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:148,

                 from C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.h:32,

                 from C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.cpp:27:

c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\bits\range_access.h:87:5: note:   'std::begin'

     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])

     ^

C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.cpp:714:18: error: 'end' was not declared in this scope

     for (char c: value)

                  ^

C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.cpp:714:18: note: suggested alternative:

In file included from c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\string:51:0,

                 from c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\random:40,

                 from c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\bits\stl_algo.h:66,

                 from c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\algorithm:62,

                 from C:\Users\zjwa1\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.2\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:148,

                 from C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.h:32,

                 from C:\Users\zjwa1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\InfluxDB-Client-for-Arduino-master\src\InfluxDbClient.cpp:27:

c:\users\zjwa1\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-80-g6c4433a-5.2.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\5.2.0\bits\range_access.h:97:5: note:   'std::end'

     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])

     ^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I leave out the wifi, etc settings. Shouldn't matter here.
The library I am using is the current 3.8.0 version.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `This example supports only InfluxDB running from unsecure (http://...)`, are you trying to connect to an https cloud database?